# get/view/emulate a Safari browser on a Windows machine?

Tags: browser, safari, mobile-safari

I need to test my application on Safari, is there an easy way to get/view/emulate a Safari browser on a Windows machine?

Answer (score -3):

Yes, this is easy. If you are referring to mobile safari then head into chrome and right click the page, then after clicking inspect element click the icon that looks like a phone. The icon is right next to a mouse pointer icon.

Comment: That's how to simulate a mobile Chrome browser. A mobile Safari browser might behave differently. Yes, they are both based on WebKit, but they do differ.